# Determine differences between incoming CSV data and existing Mongo collection for large data sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have an incoming CSV that I am trying to compare with an existing collection of mongo documents (`Note` objects) to determine additions, deletions, and updates. The incoming CSV and mongo collection are quite large at around 500K records each.

ex. csv_data

```
[{
 id: 1, text: "zzz"
}, 
{
 id: 2, text: "bbb"
}, 
{
 id: 4, text: "ddd"
}, 
{
 id: 5, text: "eee"
}]
```

Mongo collection of `Note` objects:

```
[{
 id: 1, text: "aaa"
}, 
{
 id: 2, text: "bbb"
}, 
{
 id: 3, text: "ccc"
}, 
{
 id: 4, text: "ddd"
}]
```

As a result I would want to get

an array of additions

```
[{
 id: 5, text: "eee"
}]
```

an array of removals

```
[{
 id: 3, text: "ccc"
}]
```

an array of updates

```
[{
 id: 1, text: "zzz"
}]
```

I tried using `select` statements to filter for each particular difference but it is failing / taking hours when using the real data set with all 500k records.

```
additions = csv_data.select{|record| !Note.where(id: record[:id]).exists?}
deletions = Note.all.select{|note| !csv_data.any?{|row| row[:id] == note.id}}
updates = csv_data.select do |record|
    note = Note.where(id: record[:id])
    note.exists? && note.first.text != record[:text]
end
```

How would I better optimize this?

Comment: Read up on N+1 queries, this is an antipattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: the CSV file is a snapshot of the data in the database taken at some other time, and you want a diff.

In order to get the answers you want, you need to read **every** record in the DB. Right now you are effectively doing this three times, once to obtain each statistic. Which is c.1.5m DB calls, and possibly more if there are significantly more notes on the DB than there are in the file. I'd follow these steps:

1. Read the CSV data into a hash keyed by ID
2. Read each record in the database, and for each record:
3. If the DB ID is found in the CSV hash, move it from the hash to the `updates`
4. If the DB ID isn't found in the CSV hash, add it to the `deletes`
5. When you reach the end of the DB, anything still left in the CSV hash must therefore be an `addition`

While it's still not super-slick, at least you only get to do the database I/O once instead of three times...